# Not able to get "date != null" from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongodb-query

I am not able to get the list of objects where createdDate not equal to null (basically, all date other than null) from mongodb in spring java project.

Error-prone code is:

```
@Query("{'createdDate':{$ne:null}}")
public List<MyDO> findByCretedDate();
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: how about using `$exists`?

Comment: @Query("{'createdDate':{'$exists':true}}")

Comment: Did not work for me....

Comment: Used Wrapper object insteadof permetive datatype in model class, because permetive type holds default value where there is no user defined value but object will be null where there is no user defined value.